# hide and show external components in react

Tags: reactjs

I am newbie in react and I have some trouble that I'd like to solve.
I would like to know how can I show and hide react components before and after to do a rest call.
I have the follow component:

```
class Loading {

render(){
     return (
        <div >
            <Modal isOpen={true} centered >
                <ModalHeader>Loading...</ModalHeader>
                <ModalBody >
                    <div align='center' className="mt-2 mb-2">
                        <Spinner style={{ width: '4rem', height: '4rem' }} color="primary" />
                    </div>
                </ModalBody>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    )
}
}export default Loading;
```

And I would like to show this component in other module before to call a rest api and hide this component after the data come. The ideia is some like this:

```
class List extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            show : false
        }
     }

     // HERE I WOULD LIKE TO SHOW THE LOADING COMPONENT

     callRestApi = () => {

          axiosAuth.get(url, getConfig())
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data)
            this.setState({
                eventos: response.data
            })
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            return null
        });

         // HERE I WOULD LIKE TO HIDE THE LOADING COMPONENT
     }

     render() {
         return(
              <div>
                  <Button className="mr-2" color="primary" size="sm" onClick={this.callRestApi}>List All</Button>   
              </div>
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create state that dictates whether the loading spinner is visible or not. And append one last `.then` in the promise chain to modify it.

```
class List extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        show : false,
        loaderVisible: true
    }
 }

 // HERE I WOULD LIKE TO SHOW THE LOADING COMPONENT

 callRestApi = () => {

      axiosAuth.get(url, getConfig())
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
        this.setState({
            eventos: response.data
        })
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        return null
    }).then(() => {
          this.setState({loaderVisible: false });
    });
}

 render() {
     return(
          <div>
            {
                this.state.loaderVisible? <Loading /> : ''
            }
              <Button className="mr-2" color="primary" size="sm" onClick={this.callRestApi}>List All</Button>   
          </div>
```

Then utilize ternary syntax on the spinner to determine visibility.

Comment: but where do I load my component?

Comment: @oitathi I updated my answer. Should help you out a bit.

Answer (score 2):

We use state to implement this. Here is the pseudo code.

```js
class List extends Component {
  state = { loading: false }

  callRestApi = async () => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    await fetch(...);

    this.setState({ loading: false });
  }

  render() {
    <div>
      {this.state.loading && <Loading />}
      <button onClick={this.callRestApi}>List All</button>
    </div>
  }
}
```